# How to pass the select check box values dynamically to the ajax call variables post to php variables dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I got nice select check box from eric hanes ...site :

http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

I have to pass the values that are selected from the select option in the select html tags...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.multiselect.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/prettify.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(function(){

    $("select").multiselect();

});

function select_val(){

var str = '';

        $('select[name="example-basic"] :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
            alert(str += 'var'+(i+1) +':'+ $(selected).val()+','); 
        });

                    $("#fetch").load("select.php",str,function(){});

            }


</script>

</head>
<body id="test">

<p>
    <select title="Basic example" multiple="multiple" name="example-basic" size="5">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
    <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
    <option value="option10">Option 10</option>
    <option value="option11">Option 11</option>
    <option value="option12">Option 12</option>
    </select>
</p>
<button id="select_val" onclick="select_val()"> Submit </button>
<div id="fetch"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

@Malik : I have added the code with your javascript, and if I select 2 check boxes than the values are displaying like this in first alert1 **var1:option1,** and in the second alert **var1:option1,var2:option2,**

In the above the var1:option1, and var1:option1,var2:option2, again the comma is repeating for the last value please check and also sending only one value but not repeated value if the 1st value sent than after the second value has to sent ..but not fist and second value to sent for the second checked...please check...

**but in the PHP script it is not echoing please check...**

php script :

```
<?php 

$var1= $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];

echo $var1;
echo $var2;

?>
```

I have the above code ..here the select options are selected through check box and now i have to pass the selected variables to the php variables through  the ajax call and echo in the php script..

For eg : if I select option 1 and option 2, I should get alert of option 1 and again second alert option 2..

One more help ...Now this values has to pass to the ajax call and there the ajax variables has to be dynamic... I am using the load() ajax function ..

```
$("#fetch").load("select.php",{var1:var1,var2:var2......},function(){});
```

here how to pass the check box variables dynamically in the ajax call.

```
<?php 

$var1= $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];
.
.
.


echo $var1;
echo $var2;

?>
```

Comment: Do you want to add a function handler that is executed when "select"  changes and into that execute your `$("#fetch").load(...`.  Is it that?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do here. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Yes , thanks for the reply ...I have select check box..and now i want to send the selected check box values to ajax call..k fine I can send ..if the values are known...than now the values are variable like some times may 10 or 14 or 40 ...like this for each value having the check box..k...than the user has a selected values in his mind and that selected values has to send to ajax call..and than print..

Comment: I tried by getting the length of the selected check box and push the values in array...and getting the alert in the user side...but now I want to send the selected check box ..to the server side i.e..PHP (I think you know)..i.e...using ajax call has to send...sending the variables to be dynamically in ajax function getting the values array length in php script and print the variables ..like this...I din't get.....please help

Comment: Hi @Dennis ...let me know ..U got any solution...?.please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here we go. From what i understand you have a multiselect, and want to push all those values that are selected in an array, and send it to a PHP file using ajax. Here's what i came up with:

```
$('[name=submit]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var array = [];
    $('select :selected').each(function(i,value){
        array[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    //here make your ajax call to a php file
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "path/to/file.php",
        data: { selected_values: array, otherVal: 'something else' }
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE FOR MULTI SELECT](http://jsfiddle.net/vgz1e4s8/)**

In your PHP page, use:

```
$array = $_POST['selected_values'];
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    //do something with the key/value.
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: @MaheshCholleti if it's working now, you can accept my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get values of all the selected options like the following:

```
var arr = []; 
$('select[name="example-basic"] :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
  arr[i] = $(selected).val(); 
});
```

or Using the .val() function on a multi-select list will return an array of the selected values:

```
var selectedValues = $('select[name="example-basic"]').val();
```

By using above jQuery code it will give you the value in array format. Where you can pass that array into php like the following:

```
$("#fetch").load("select.php",{var1:arr[0],var2:arr[1]......},function(){});
```

where 'arr[0]' is first selected option value and similarly so on.

**Edited Code:**

```
var str = '';
        $('select[name="example-basic"] :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
           str += 'var'+(i+1) +'='+ $(selected).val()+'&'; 
        });

        $("#fetch").load("select.php",str,function(){});
```

Above is the code for your javascript and below is defined how you can get the values in server side :

```
<?php 

$var1= $_GET['var1'];
$var2 = $_GET['var2'];
.
.
.


echo $var1;
echo $var2;

?>
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: HI ..but the values are the dynamically changes in the selected options like sometimes will get 10 and after 30 ...and after 40...and 10 ..depends on the data...the variables that are sending to the select.php in that page also should be dynamically get the values acoording to the array in javascript passing and also in the php script also dynamically accept the javascript values...like in php script ...$var1=$_POST['var1'];  $var2= $_POST['var2']....

Comment: The selected check box values are changes every time..in load ajax() function also ...has to be dynamically changes the variables using for loop or is there any other way....?

Comment: @Mahesh I have updated my answer. Please check and hope this will solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: HI @Malik ..please check the code ..I have edited with your code...Its not wotking...please check

Comment: In the alert values are coming but , how to get the values from the js to PHP script...?