# How to set cursor position in particular input text in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying set the cursor to the selected input box , if the user is selected in the second input text box without entering the value in the first input box than the cursor should go to the first input box.

```
<html>

<script>

$( "#cic_name" ).focus(function() {

                                    var luname=$("#site").val();


                                    if(luname.length>0){

                                }
                                    else{
                                            alert("please select TG value");
                                        }

                        });

</script>


<body>

ENTER TG: <input type="text" id="site" name="sitename"  placeholder="TG Name">

ENTER CIC: <input type="text" id="cic_name" name="cic"  placeholder="CiC Name">


</body>

</html>
```

How to set the cursor position in the selected input box i.e..(id= site) if the user din't enter any thing in the first input box.

I am wondering if there any cursor events are there.. I din't get.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('[name=textbox2]').focus(function(){
    if($('[name=textbox1]').val() == ''){
        $('[name=textbox1]').focus();
    }
});
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/erj3qpw7/)**

Comment: I am very thankful for answer and I need one help ....I have posted one question no one is answering if you can ...please check this link ......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111943/how-to-pass-the-select-check-box-values-dynamically-to-the-ajax-call-variables-p

Answer (score 0):

There is a better approach to it. Try this

```
$(function(){
 if($("#sitesite").val()=="")
   $("#sitesite").focus();
 else
   $("#cic_name").focus();       
});
```

Comment: This may work, however, when the user has a textarea on their site for let's say a newsletter or something, users cannot fill in their email to subscribe, because your function will focus the wrong element all the time.

Comment: Agreed. Looking at the sample, I assumed it is the first element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This does it in 1 extra line: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qk53ywh/1/)

```
$( "#cic_name" ).focus(function() {
      var luname=$("#site").val();
         if(luname.length>0){
            }
           else{
           alert("please select TG value");
            $("#site").focus();
             }
            });
```